# Regular Expression fails in IE, but works in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have the following asp.net markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"   
ValidationGroup="passwordValidation"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
ControlToValidate="txtPassword" Text="Required" ValidationGroup="passwordValidation" />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPassword"  
Text="Passwords should contain a minimum of 7 characters with at least one numeric 
character." ValidationExpression="^(?=.*\d{1})(?=.*[a-zA-Z]{2}).{7,}$"  
ValidationGroup="passwordValidation" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

If I type in a password like test1234, it passes in chrome and firefox, but the message that my password should contain a minimum of 7 characters with at least one numeric character is shown in internet explorer

Comment: I tested the above code in VS2010 on IE8 and cannot reproduce the problem. Can you provide more specifics?

Comment: ...in particular, which version(s) of IE are you testing it on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably getting bitten by the infamous [IE regex lookahead bug](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug).  You should be able to work around that by making the length check a lookahead like the other conditions, and putting it first.

```
^(?=.{7,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]{2}).*
```

But I think I see another problem.  `(?=.*[a-zA-Z]{2})` matches two *consecutive* letters; is that really your intent?  If you want to require at least two letters, but not necessarily consecutive, you should use  `(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z])`.

Comment: I will give this a shot and let u know.  I am reading the post about it.  I am new to regular expressions, so lookahead is going over my head.

Comment: You might want to check out this site, if you haven't already: http://www.regular-expressions.info/