# Regular expression validator not working in sharepoint designer

Tags: .net, regex, sharepoint

I am validating a SharePoint list field by adding a regular expression validator using SharePoint Designer.  The list will be inside a DataFormWebPart created by SP Designer.

Validation : The value entered in the field must be in `0.00` format. the error message is populated irrespective of the value entered inside the text box.  Even if I enter correct value like ( `1.23`) even then the error message is displayed.

Is this issue similar to the one below?

[ASP.NET Regular Expression Validator Not Working on Internet Explorer 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761148/asp-net-regular-expression-validator-not-working-on-internet-explorer-7)

If it matches, please suggest to write a lookahead pattern for this regular expression. the
regular expression is

```
^[0-9]1.[0-9]2$
```

Answer (score 2):

You were probably trying to do this: `[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{2}` (where `{1}` and `{2}` are [quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)), but don't do that either.  The pseudo-quantifier `{1}` does nothing but add clutter to your regex.  If you really want to accept only one digit before the dot (`.`), use this:

```
^[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}$
```

If you want to accept one *or more* digits before the dot, you can use this:

```
^[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$
```

And if you don't want to accept numbers with leading zeroes (`01.23`, `000.00`, etc.) use this:

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)\.[0-9]{2}$
```

`(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)` matches one or more digits where the first digit is at least at least `1`, or exactly one zero (`0.10`, `1.23`, `456.78`, etc.).

You also mentioned lookaheads, but there's no need for them in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The number you supply as an example would not match the regex expression you provide. The Regex for 0.00 format is `^[0-9][.][0-9][0-9]$` The dot is a reserved character. So you would need to put it in brackets in a sharepoint string. if it is javascript you would escape the . with the slash key so the regex would become `^[0-9]\\.[0-9][0-9]$` Because backslash is a reserved javascript character you probably need double backslash to get a single backslash for the regex.

Comment: ^[0-9]\.[0-9]{2}$  and ^[0-9][.][0-9][0-9]$, both are working perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: am also trying to do same but it is not working means when am simply adding validator to designer form and running my page then it shows error as
"The type System.Web.UI.WebControls.RegularExpressionValidator, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a could not be found or it is not registered as safe"